# VLC start video on specific monitor through command line

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, video, display, vlc

I am trying to control VLC on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop from my Xubuntu 16.04 laptop. I originally used the command `vlc -f myVideo.avi` which ran the video in the terminal(side note how cool is that).

I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1035787/open-a-movie-with-vlc-from-command-line-via-ssh) which did fix the issue, but it is now displaying on the incorrect monitor. I tried `export DISPLAY=:1` for 1-4 and on those it would not display at all. I tried `man export` hoping for options, but there is no man page for it. I can only get a display for 0, but that is not on the correct monitor. How can I specify which monitor I want VLC to play on through the command line?