# How to output VLC only through HDMI?

Tags: command-line, vlc, hdmi

How to output VLC player results only through HDMI output? As now I run `vlc -f --play-and-exit file.mp4` and It starts to run even in command-line. I want to run it in background and view only through hdmi output. How to do it?? Don't forget that I use terminal.

Comment: If you launch your process with ` &` at the end it will automatically go to the background. For info on VLC output you might find this useful. https://wiki.videolan.org/Video_Output/

Comment: This looks familiar.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/818980/vlc-start-video-on-specific-monitor-through-command-line?rq=1

Comment: You might also find [this useful](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474485/commands-to-run-when-connecting-hdmi?rq=1)